# I want to change this mySQL to a Laravels ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

MySQL query:

```
select 
     count(distinct vote_checks.user_id) AS count from vote_checks
join 
     vote_items on vote_checks.item_id=vote_items.id
where 
     vote_items.vote_id = 3;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far..

Comment: $check_point = Vote_check::where('item_id', $item[0]->vote_checks->vote_id)->first();                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////$chk_point = DB::table('vote_checks')
          ->join('vote_checks', function($join)
          {
              $join->on('vote_checks.item_id', '=', 'vote_items.id');
          })->where('vote_items.vote_id', $board)->select('vote_checks.user_id')->distinct()->count();
////$chk_point=Vote_check::where(, $board)->get();//distinct()->count('user_id');
        //$chk_point = Vote_check::where('item_id', '1'->vote_item->vote_id)->get();

Comment: sorry i first use stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
DB::table('vote_checks')
->select(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT vote_checks.user_id) as count')
->leftJoin('vote_items','vote_checks.item_id', '=', 'vote_items.id')
->where('vote_items.vote_id',3)
->get();
```